# Java IO: Reading a file that is still being written

Tags: java, scala, inputstream, outputstream

I am creating a program which needs to read from a file that is still being written.

The main question is this: If the read and write will be performed using `InputStream` and `OutputStream` classes running on a separate thread, **what are the catches and edge cases that I will need to be aware of in order to prevent data corruption?**

In case anyone is wondering if I have considered other, non-`InputStream` based approach, the answer is yes, I have but unfortunately it's not possible in this project since the program uses libraries that only works with `InputStream` and `OutputStream`.

Also, several readers have asked why this complications is necessary. Why not perform reading after the file has been written completely?

The reason is efficiency. The program will perform the following

1. Download a series of byte chunks of 1.5MB each. The program will receive thousands of such chunks that can total up to 30GB. Also, chunks are downloaded concurrently in order to maximize bandwidth, so they **may arrive out of order**.
2. The program will send each chunk for processing as soon as they have arrived. Please note that they will be sent for processing **in order**. If chunk m arrives before chunk m-1 does, they will be buffered on disk until chunk m-1 arrives and is sent for processing.
3. perform processing of these chunks starting from chunk 0 up to chunk n until every chunks has been processed
4. Resend the processed result back.

If we are to wait for the whole file to be transferred, it will introduce a huge delay on what is supposed to be a real-time system.

Comment: I am more wondering why you consider reading and writing the same file at the same time. Sure it can be done, but it opens a can of worms of potential problems.

Comment: Jägermeister is right. Just because a library works with `Input/OutputStreams` doesn't mean you need to read and write a file at the same time.

Comment: @Jägermeister Please see my updated post. Also, what exactly are these can worm of potential problems?

Comment: @lolski Wouldn't it make sense to do this processing in memory? Since you don't apparently need to have the whole 30GB before starting the processing, it would seem that you could process the data in chunks. If the libraries only use streams, you can always create your own suitable implementations. Your example code doesn't really provide much information, so it's hard to come up with a decent suggestion.

Comment: @Kayaman reworded my questions completely. Basically buffering on disk is needed and I can't get away with it. Also, the API I work with AWS S3 and Apache Commons Compress is written to accept In/OutputStream or File instances only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your problem (as you've cleared it up now) is that you can't start processing until chunk#1 has arrived, and you need to buffer every chunk#N (N > 1) until you can process them.

I would write each chunk to their own file and create a custom `InputStream` that will read every chunk in order. While downloading the chunkfile would be named something like `chunk.1.downloading` and when the whole chunk is loaded it will be renamed to `chunk.1`.

The custom `InputStream` will check to see if file `chunk.N` exists (where N = 1...X). If not, it will block. Each time a chunk has been downloaded completely, the `InputStream` is notified, it will check if the downloaded chunk was the next one to be processed. If yes, read as normally, otherwise block again.

Comment: This approach definitely makes sense. However, for the sake of clarity, can you specify why this approach is preferable compared to the approach that that I proposed, i.e. what are the factors that makes the aforementioned "read while writing" operation not preferred?

Comment: Well one clear advantage is that in case of a crash you can clearly see what the state of the system was, then resume operation. I can imagine that saving the chunks as their own S3 files could have some advantage as well. It'll definitely be a more straightforward implementation than trying to have 2 streams chase each other.

Answer (score 2):

Use a **RandomAccessFile**. Via a **getChannel** or such one could use a **ByteBuffer**.

You will not be able to "insert" or "delete" middle parts of the file. For such a purpose your original approach would be fine, but using two files.

For concurrency: to keep in synch you could maintain one single object model of the file, do changes there. Only the pending changes need to be kept in memory, other hierarchical data could be reread and reparsed as needed.

Comment: I will look into it. Is there any file-system specific issues that we need to be aware of that you know?

Comment: I generally check the modification time for external interference (like starting an app twice). A **WatchService** to receive such external modifications is a nice plus, but do not take a WatchService to be perfect: not every way of change might be detected, like via the clipboard. After you got a basic working app, you may consider file attributes per OS, locks and such.

Answer (score 0):

You should use PipedInputStream and PipedOutputStream:

```
static Thread newCopyThread(InputStream is, OutputStream os) {
    Thread t = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
            try {
                while (true) {
                    int size = is.read(buffer);
                    if (size < 0) break;
                    os.write(buffer, 0, size);
                }
                is.close();
                os.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
            }
        }
    };
    return t;
}

public void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    ByteArrayInputStream bi = new ByteArrayInputStream("abcdefg".getBytes());
    PipedInputStream is = new PipedInputStream();
    PipedOutputStream os = new PipedOutputStream(is);
    Thread p = newCopyThread(bi, os);
    Thread c = newCopyThread(is, System.out);
    p.start();
    c.start();
    p.join();
    c.join();
}
```